# How to change user profile page url structure in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change user profile page url structure in wordpress.
My current url structure is http://www.mydomainname.com/user/vendorname=testname
I want to change the url to http://www.mydomainname.com/user/testname .
The functionality in user profile page should remain same as now.

Comment: Do you mean the author archive page? If so, by default, links to that page are already `example.com/author/username`

Comment: Sorry. This is not author archive page. I have create a special type of user page for my project.

Comment: It might be worth explaining what you've custom created in your question.